# Highcharts apply different background color to all month of each year

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a column chart created using the Highcharts plugin and the data is fetched from SharePoint. It works perfectly, except that I would like to add an additional feature. I would like all the months of the same year to be the same color. For example all 2013 month would be blue, 2014 green, etc. This is my code so far:

JS

```
    var columnColors = ["#5179D6", "#66CC66", "#EF2F41", "#FFC700", "#61BDF2", "#FF7900", "#7588DD", "#2F5E8C", "#07BACE", "#BAE55C", "#BA1871", "#FFFFCC", "#BDE6FC", "#C7C7C7", "#ADA8FF", "#2FA675", "#33CCFF", "#6666FF", "#0099CC", "#FF9900", "#009999", "#669999", "#009933", "#FF9999", "#3366FF", "#FF6600", "51A9FF", "FF9800", "FF4700"];

chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    colors: columnColors,

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false
    },


    title: {
        text: ROCharts,
        x: -20, //center
    },
    credits: { enabled: false
    },

    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: '#606060',
                style: {
                    fontFamily: '\'Lato\', sans-serif',
                    lineHeight: '11px',
                    fontSize: '10px'
                },
                formatter: function () {

                    if (this.y != 0 && (parameterChartsText === "Monthly Cost Savings" || parameterChartsText === "Monthly Expenditure")) {
                        return '<b>' + accounting.formatMoney([this.y], "$ ") + '</b>';
                    } else if (this.y != 0) {
                        return '<b>' + this.y + '</b> ' + currencySymbol;
                    }

                }
            },
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0,
            groupPadding: 0,
            shadow: false,
            colorByPoint: true //add different colors per column
        }
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: monthsArray
    },
    yAxis: {
        gridLineColor: "#ddd",
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: parameterChartsText + " " + currencySymbol
        }
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'This chart shows value from a SharePoint list using SPServices',
        x: -20
    },

    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.values}' + currencySymbol + '</b>{point.y}',
        valueDecimals: decimales,
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true,
    },

    exporting: {
        enabled: true,
        sourceWidth: 600,
        sourceHeight: 400,
        scale: 2
    },

    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        enabled: true,
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        padding: 5,
        itemMarginTop: 10,
        itemMarginBottom: 5,
        itemStyle: {
            lineHeight: '14px'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        showInLegend: true,
        type: 'column',
        name: parameterChartsText,
        data: valuesArray
    }]
});
```

[image: Chart]

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternate solution:

Make each year a separate series. 
By default, each year will be a different color.

In this case, you will need to specify x values in your data.

`example`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/uLo7f6nf/

Another option, which I personally find preferable, is to leave all of the columns the same color, and instead alternate the background each year by adding a plot band:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/uLo7f6nf/3/

Another method which is perhaps a middle ground between the two: supply only two slightly different colors for the chart, so that each year will alternate between two shades of a color.

This approach allows the user to differentiate between the years, but keeps the user from being overloaded by an unnecessary mix of colors:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/uLo7f6nf/5/

Answer (score 1):

For each of points in `valuesArray` you should set color property. Now each of columns will have that color. Highcharts doesn't have `colorByMonth` or anything like this in options.

Another solution will be to set array of colors, and duplicate each color 12 times:

```
var columnColors = ["#5179D6", "#5179D6", "#5179D6", "#5179D6", "#5179D6", "#5179D6", "#5179D6", "#5179D6", "#5179D6", "#5179D6", "#5179D6", "#5179D6",
                    "#66CC66", "#66CC66", "#66CC66", "#66CC66", "#66CC66", "#66CC66", "#66CC66", "#66CC66", "#66CC66", "#66CC66", "#66CC66", "#66CC66",
                    "#EF2F41",  ... ];


chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    colors: columnColors,
    ...
});
```

Comment: I thought about the duplication, but the thing is that as the years progress, I would have to keep adding 12 more repeated colors. It is not a big deal to add them, but I was hoping for some "automation". Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to set for each point color separately, then it's easies way.